# Flex 3: is md5 possible?

Tags: apache-flex, encryption

Is there a way to use some kind of encryption (md5, hash, etc...) to determine if two arraycollections are the same or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActionScript Comparing Arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890178/actionscript-comparing-arrays)

Comment: nothing came up in the suggested threads when I created the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are a couple libraries for generating a hash. http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/

Edit: Answered already [ActionScript Comparing Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890178/actionscript-comparing-arrays)

Comment: That's certainly it, but it doesn't seem to work with array collections :(

Comment: Ah, sorry then. My actionscript is a bit rusty. Does this help? http://forums.adobe.com/thread/706719?tstart=1

Comment: That's sort of a brute force way of doing it... which is what i was hoping to avoid.  My array collections could potentially be quite large... I'm trying to minimize load times, so checking each element of an array collection against it's counterpart element in the other array collection is going to have to be my last resort

Comment: @Brds: However else do you think you could compare two array collections instead of comparing each element?

Comment: @splash He's looking to do a binary hash on the object and compare the hash values. I'm not sure it is possible.

Comment: @Joshua Dale: A useful hash would examine every element to compute the hash.

Comment: @GregS that is true. I don't see any reason why you couldn't create one from the arraycollections binary representation however. I don't work with the flash platform often so I'm sure there are better ways.