# trouble array and strict equal actionscrpt3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a trouble with arrays, on actionscript 3.0, I have read on adobe page that I can check if two var have the same information.

```
var num1:Number = new Number(1);
var num2:Number = new Number(1);

trace(num1 == num2); 
// true in ActionScript 3.0, false in ActionScript 2.0

trace(num1 === num2); // true in ActionScript 3.0, false in ActionScript 2.0

I tried to do a condition based on that, this is basically my code

var sol:Array= new Array();

sol.push("a");

sol.push("b");

sol.push("c");

var letters:Array= new Array();

sol.push("a");

sol.push("b");

sol.push("c");

btngo_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK ,goshow);

function goshow (event:MouseEvent):void{


    if(trace(sol===letters) ==true ){

        gotoAndPlay("win");

    }else {

        gotoAndPlay("lose");

    }

}
```

The first problem is the trace (sol === letters) send me a value of false.

The second problem is that I think my condition does not work, I tryed with another condition that send me a true value and it keeps to send me to "lose".

I really apreciate the time you have spend reading the post and wish you a great week.

Comment: When you create two arrays, you are creating two completely different objects (even if the array has the same contents).  So they will never evaluated to being equal.

Answer (score 1):

In your sample, you are creating two separate array objects.

`var sol:Array= new Array();` & `var letters:Array= new Array();`

Regardless of the content of the arrays, they will always be different objects and therefor will never evaluate as being the same.   `sol == letters` will always return false because they are instantiated as two different objects.

---

For you second part  `if(trace(sol===letters) ==true )`:

What you're evaluating here is the return value of the trace function.  Since trace returns void (I believe) this will always evaluate as false (regardless of what you pass into trace.

---

What you likely want to do, is evaluate the contents of your array, not the array itself.  Here is a question that addressed that:  [ActionScript Comparing Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890178/actionscript-comparing-arrays)

Comment: Thanks alot, I check the question and it solves a lot of my issues, I wish you to have a great day

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comments and in the other answer, you are comparing two objects, not their contents.

Here's a function you could use compare the contents of the two arrays the way you want :

```
function arraysMatch(first:Array, second:Array):Boolean
{
    if (first.length == second.length)
    {
       for (var index:int = 0;index < first.length;index++)
       {
           if (first[index] != last[index])
              return false;
       {
       return true;
    }
         else
             return false;

}
// usage

if (arraysMatch(first,second))
{
   // arrays have matching contents
   // do something 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, that was quick.

I have not think of that solution =D